# cmake library - relative path fails but absolute path succeeds

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-language

I have a cmakefile that's very basic.
This is the relevant portion:

```
# The object files of ds
set(DS_LIB_FOLDER ../../build/)
set(DS_LIB ds)
get_filename_component(DS_LIB_FOLDER_ABS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${DS_LIB_FOLDER}" ABSOLUTE)
set(DS_LIB_PATH ${DS_LIB_FOLDER_ABS}/lib${DS_LIB}.a)
```

When I remove the absolute path and use relative (see the last line) like so:

```
# The object files of ds
set(DS_LIB_FOLDER ../../build/)
set(DS_LIB ds)
get_filename_component(DS_LIB_FOLDER_ABS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${DS_LIB_FOLDER}" ABSOLUTE)
set(DS_LIB_PATH ${DS_LIB_FOLDER}/lib${DS_LIB}.a)
```

I get the error:

> ninja: error: '../../build/libds.a', needed by 'HostUnitTest', missing
> and no known rule to make it

It also fails if I use `gnu makefiles` as the build system.

I made sure the file exists:

```
user@wsl:/mnt/c/work/project/product/tests/hosts$ ls -l ../../build/libds.a
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 333466584 May 25 13:19 ../../build/libds.a
user@wsl:/mnt/c/work/project/product/tests/hosts$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user 1471 May 25 14:13 CMakeLists.txt
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4096 May 25 14:13 build
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user  272 May 25 11:54 main.cpp
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4096 May 24 10:50 unit_tests
```

**QUESTION**
Why does it fail?  In both cases, the relative path is used.
In the absolute case, the relative path is used implicitly in the derivation of the absolute path.

Comment: The relative paths are relative to the current directory when you *build*, not when you invoke `cmake` or to the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I see that now. Seems like `cmake` should take care to modify the relative paths when generating the build files in a `build` directory.

Comment: I don't think there's enough info here to reproduce the problem. where is `DS_LIB_PATH` being used, and what is it being used for? whether and how relative paths are interpreted depends on what command the path is being passed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use relative paths to `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`, the path where the currently being processed `CMakeLists.txt` is located. I.e. replace

```
set(DS_LIB_FOLDER ../../build/)
```

with

```
set(DS_LIB_FOLDER "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../build/")
```